# How can I use a script to get the IP address from ifconfig if the size of the IP changes in size with each connection?

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, bash, scripts

I'm currently working with this

> ```
>      IFTUN="$(ifconfig tun)"
>      IPADD=${IFTUN:106:13}
>      echo $IPADD
> ```

But if the size of the IP address changes this isn't going to work anymore.

> ```
>      inet addr:1.2.3.4  P-t-P:1.2.3.4  Mask:255.255.254.0
>      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>      RX packets:1151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
> ```

So what I'm after is a way to get the IP from ifconfig no matter what the number of chars is "1.2.3.4" or say "111.22.3.44" or even "111.222.333.444"

Comment: `ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'`

Comment: `ip addr | grep 'state UP' -A2 | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f1  -d'/'`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your IP Adress from `Ifconfig` you can use this:

```
echo `ifconfig tun0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://'`
```

This command will get the IP address of `tun0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ip` command insted of `ifconfig`, which is deprecated.

```
ipAddr=$( ip a s eth0 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {print $2}' )
```

Sample output: `172.16.2.136/16`

If you don't want to include the CIDR, use this:

```
ipAddr=$( ip a s eth0 | awk '/inet.*brd/ {print $2}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1}' )
```

Sample output: `172.16.2.136`

Comment: `ip a s eth0 | awk -F"[ /]+" '/scope global/{print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

I would not use ifconfig because at least on some distro's it's being replaced by ip.

If you know your interface you can do this:

ip addr |grep eth0 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}'

It will give you the mask also which you can cut off like this

ip addr |grep eth0 |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |cut -d "/" -f 1

I'm assuming you are using bash for your script.  If you are using another language you could also get your host name and look up it's ip.

Comment: Yes I am using bash and I didn't know about the ip addr option so I'll be going with the "ip addr |grep tun |grep inet |awk '{print $2}' |cut -d "/" -f 1" option which seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks for the help